# Using Parallels to test Web applications in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, pylons, parallels

I am developing a Web application in Pylons on the Mac.  My development server serves pages to http://127.0.0.1:5000/.  Is there any way that I can access this page from Parallels for testing with IE without having to set up a development environment in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loopback address (127.0.0.1) is only accessible by your local machine. In this case Parallels is considered another (virtual) machine. While Parallels can be configured to use the same IP address as the host operating system, it cannot share the loopback address.

To access pages served on your Mac from Parallels you can change the IP (host) used by Pylons to that of your local network instead of the loopback address. In the **development.ini** change the **host** setting.

Comment: Is the IP of my local network the same as the IP of my router?

Comment: You can find the IP address of your Mac from System Preferences -> Network. But it may be easier to set the IP to 0.0.0.0 so that it will listen on all addresses. Then you might be able to use the name of your mac as Eifion suggests.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I set it to my machine's local IP and it works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your machine name instead of 127.0.0.1, e.g. http://MyIMac:5000/ ?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I forgot to exclude my mac's ip address from the windows browser's proxy settings (I was using a corporate proxy in the browser).