# Web Dev on MacOSX, how to check IE compatIbility?

Tags: internet-explorer, macos, browser, cross-browser

How can I check IE compatibility when I'm developing a website on MacOSX, primarily using Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best tool for testing IE from a Mac - without a PC...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086778/best-tool-for-testing-ie-from-a-mac-without-a-pc)

Comment: Also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102799/using-parallels-to-test-web-applications-in-ie and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586980/test-ie6-on-mac-os-x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070071/rails-how-can-i-test-in-ie-while-developing-under-mac-os-x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844682/is-there-a-ie-tester-for-mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a [parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) windows install to test IE and Firefox. That will show you exactly what a windows user would see.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [Virtual PC for Mac from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/australia/office/mac/virtualpc7/default.aspx).  They keep images of various windows builds for developer to use. They're basically Windows and the Browser only.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Wine](http://winehq.org) to install and run the IE versions you need. I am not a Mac user myself but I think you can get a good environment with [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org).

Comment: This is a much simpler solution as long as you're not using any Windows-specific technology like ActiveX, behaviors or filters. The rendering engine works, but pages made using, e.g., IE7.js or pngfix will look wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I use Parallels & also use Adobe's Browserlab which lets you test virtually all browsers. This is useful as even with a virtual machine you can't test easily all versions of IE, unless you have multiple VMs, which is just too much.  Good luck.

https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org) is a free VM solution from Oracle(formerly Sun) that works pretty well. It isn't as feature full and easy to use as Parallels or VMWare Fusion, but Virtual Box is free. All require a valid Windows install/license.